# Clustering using density fields

Tags: clustering

I like to tinker in my spare time with clustering algorithms.

Over the past few days I was attempting to tinker with a clustering algorithm using density fields of the data.

I tried several variations and I was surprised that my algorithms were reasonably stable and robust.

I want to continue exploring this avenue but I'd like to understand what other popular variations are out there.

I've don't a cursory review of the literature but unfortunately was not able to find a decent survey that deals with density based algorithms.

I'd appreciate it if I could get a pointer to such a survey or a list of the establish algorithms.

Comment: Elaine...I'm your desnity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBSCAN and OPTICS (the latter is a generalisation of the former) are well-known density-based clustering algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting article comparing the different clustering algos in Python: [here](http://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparing_clustering_algorithms.html)

As suggested above DBSCAN is a good choice. They promote an improvement of it called HDBSCAN.
Affinity Propagation is not density based but you can achieve pretty similar results. The main difference is the handling of noise and/or singletons